# haversine formula definition for sql

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, android-sqlite

Hi iam currently working on an android app which stores the details of shops in an sql database and the users use the app to search for the shops around them.

i found a formula called haversine to find distance between two points with there lat and lng values.

```
    SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians(         lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM     markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

but iam confused with this i don't know which lat and lng value refers to what!
if some one could re-write the above code such that my user has position lat1 & lng1 
for the shopkeeper it is lat2 and lng2.  Also can u tell me what is that a in

```
  acos
```

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? If the latter, it has a native geography data type that will let you do this calculation w/o all the messy math.

Comment: can you give me some information about that..? when using sql,and to use that property in sql server if i use in this math kind of a way does it increase my server cost...? compared to using the service that you told..? @BenThul

Comment: There's a lot to know. Here's a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx. As for doing it the way you're doing it, you're never going to be able to use an index to perform that search. The geospatial datatypes come with indexing, so queries like "get me points within a certain radius" are efficient.

Comment: so thus by using this regular sql queries for finding things around the user from database table would make a large server cost difference !?  @BenThul

Comment: Yes. It comes down to a concept called SARGability. That is, right now, to satisfy your query, you need to calculate the distance from your given point to every other point and then only return those that meet your criteria (in this case, distance < 25). By using the geography datatype, the engine is smart enough to exclude a lot of points and is able to efficiently narrow in on those points that have a chance of satisfying the criteria.

Comment: can you also tell me tutorials related to this iam interested .Also please tell me some online hosting sites which support this. Does google cloud offer this!? @BenThul

Comment: I've pointed you at the documentation for this for SQL Server. If you're using that, look at all of that and try some things. If you're not using SQL Server, you'll have to see if there's similar functionality in whatever RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The order of lat/lngs don't matter.  Think of it this way... the distance from point A to point B is that same as the distance from point B to point A.

In your code example, the 37 is a latitude point and the -122 is a longitude point.

acos is the arc cosine trigonemetric function.  Explanation here:  [ArcCosine](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/trigonometry/arccos.htm)

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(Lat1) ) * cos( radians( Lat2 ) ) * cos( radians(Lng2) - radians(Lng1) ) + sin( radians(Lat1) ) * sin( radians(Lat2)))) AS distance 
FROM     markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: ha i didn't mean that what i asked was that for my user i have a latitude and longitude value and same for the case of shops,  but inthe above code i have only two variables lat and lng!,

Comment: I understand.  What I meant is that the 37 in your code represents a latitude and the -122 represents a longitude.  Instead of hard-coding those numbers, you should make them variables.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are so few answers for haversine SQL on the web, I am adding a full version of it adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula for your copy-paste workflow:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION haversine(Lat1, Lng1, Lat2, Lng2) AS 
    2 * 6335 
        * asin(sqrt(
            pow(sin((radians(Lat2) - radians(Lat1)) / 2), 2)
            + cos(radians(Lat1))
            * cos(radians(Lat2))
            * pow(sin((radians(Lng2) - radians(Lng1)) / 2), 2)
        ));
```

I needed it for https://duckdb.org. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: seems to be missing the arcsin of the sqrt?